# Explicit description of $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^1}(-1)$ as a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quasicoherent-sheaves, line-bundles

I understand the construction of $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^1}(-1)$ as a sheaf on $\Bbb{P}_\Bbb{C}^1$, but I'm trying to understand how exactly does this define a line bundle and why people call this the "tautological line bundle".

Following the suggestion of "tautological", my first idea was to define the map:
\begin{align*}
\pi:\Bbb{A}^2&\to\Bbb{P}^1\\
(x_0,x_1)&\mapsto (x_0:x_1) 
\end{align*}

whose fibers are clearly lines.

Now, I can neither see how to define the trivialization maps nor how this relates to the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^1}(-1)$, so probably I'm on the wrong path.

I'm having a hard time trying to come up with different ideas, because I don't even know how to find a variety $X$ so that $\pi:X\to\Bbb{P}^1$ is the line bundle I'm looking for.

Comment: You're on the right path. The problem is that $\pi : \mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ is not well-defined at the origin. To resolve the indeterminacy of $\pi$, try blowing up $\mathbb{A}^2$ at the origin and check that the rational map $\pi$ is well defined on the blowup. Check that the usual charts for the blowup give you the trivializations you seek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it helps to think about it if you don't choose a basis right away. Let $V$ be a two-dimensional vector space and $\mathbb{P}(V)$ the variety of lines through the origin in $V$. Then $\mathbb{P}(V)$ certainly has a trivial two-dimensional vector bundle $V \times \mathbb{P}(V)$. Inside this bundle is the more interesting bundle
$$
\{ (v, \lambda) \in V \times \mathbb{P}(V): v \text{ is on the line } \lambda\}.
$$
This is why it's called tautological: a point of $\mathbb{P}(V)$ is a *line* and this is the bundle that attaches *that line* to it.

Of course you can't compute like this; you need coordinates. In coordinates, what you want is
$$
\{(x_0, y_0), [z_0: w_0] \in \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1 : \exists a \in \mathbb{C} \text{ such that } az_0 = x_0 \text{ and } aw_0 = y_0 \}.
$$
together with its normal projection to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: And then what does this have to do with $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ still remains to be checked -- the exercise being to describe an identification between the sheaf of sections of this bundle and $\mathcal{O}(-1)$.

Comment: Is there a general way to explicit $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^1}(n)$ as a line bundle? Thank you!

Comment: Absolutely, it is just $\big\{ (p = [p_0:p_1],v)\in \mathbf{CP}^1\times\mathbf{C}^2\mid v\text{ lies on the line }[p_0^n:p_1^n]  \big\}$.